# Change my album from unlisted to public in Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos

I mistakenly created my album and set it to unlisted and now I'm unable to locate my album.

Answer (score 1):

Google+ Photos is now just Google Photos.

Your photos can be found at https://photos.google.com. All of your albums are on the "[Albums](https://photos.google.com/albums)" page, accessible from the menu on the left. That includes your unlisted albums.

Under the auto-created albums ("Shared", "People", "Places", etc.) they're listed in generally date descending order (based on the photos in each album) so the album you created should be right at the top. You can also search for the name of the album; when you start typing into the search box you'll be offered auto-complete entries that match your album names.

To share your album, simply open it and click the "Share" icon in the top right. The rest is fairly self-explanatory.